# Isolating specific elements held within brackets of a list- Python

Tags: python, list, loops, split, strip

```
ini_list = "[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]"
res = ini_list.strip('[]')
print(res)
('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')

result = res.strip('()')
print(result)
'G 02', 'UV', '2.73'
```

I have a list that consists of three elements held within brackets, I want to extract each element from the brackets and assign it a variable: ('G 02', 'UV', '2.73'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), etc etc etc and I would like to assign variables to this list so that the outcome is as follows:
The first parameter held within the bracket should = element
The second parameter which may be empty in some cases should = reason
The third parameter which is always a number and may be in the second position if there is no reason held within the bracket should = time.

thus the outcome should be presented as follows:

Element = G 05, Load 23A_UF, Load 21A_UF... the first element of each bracket listed.
Reason = Over-Speed, , , second element of the bracket that is not a number
Time = 1.63, 11.37, 11.38, the third element in the bracket which is a number(will always be a number)
I have numerous lists that contain those parameters that I would like to later use to plot various things and so would like to extract each parameter from the list and associate it with the specific variable. The number of brackets held with ini_list varies so would like to have a loop that cycles through.

I tried to do it with the help of Prathamesh Jadhav by:

```
ini_list = "[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]"

res = ini_list.strip('[]')

result = res.strip('()')

result1 = result.split(',')

result1=[x.strip(" ") for x in result1]
result1=[x.strip("''") for x in result1]

element = result1[0]
print("element:",element)
reason =result1[1]
print("reason:",reason)
time=result1[2]
print("time:",time)
```

However this only works for the first bracket and does not cycle through the entire list of brackets so a loop is required. But when I try use a loop I cant get rid of the brackets and punctuation to isolate each variable.

how do i get it so it assigns variables to each parameter as mentioned above and so it prints as so:

```
element = G 05, Load 23A_UF, Load 21A_UF, G 02 
reason = Over-Speed, , ,UV
time = 1.63, 11.37, 11.38, 2.73
```

Comment: You're looking for [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: If you change all the `'('` to `'['` and the `')'` to `']'` and the `'` to `"`, you can parse it with `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have the list as a string and not as a list?

```
ini_list = [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]

for thing in ini_list:
    if len(thing) == 3:
        element = thing[0]
        reason = thing[1]
        time = thing[2]
    else:
        element = thing[0]
        time = thing[1]
        reason = ""
    print(f"{element} {reason} {time}")
```

works if you can use `ini_list` as a list instead of string.

EDIT: Since the `ini_list` is given as a string. You can try using regular expressions.

```
import re


ini_list = "[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]"

#extract all tuples by regular expression
result = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)',ini_list)

target_list = []
for tup in result:
    items = tup.split(',')
    if len(items) == 3:
        target_list.append((item[0], item[1], item[2]))
    else:
        target_list.append((item[0], None, item[1]))
```

Comment: Yeah it needs to be a string and I want to split that string into groups to make a list, and making those groups be (fault), (fault), etc etc with each one being (element, reason, time), (element, reason, time) therefore getting each bracket into a list so that I can cycle the list and extract the element, reason and time from each bracket.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. I am basically trying to split the string using the commas, so that the string is only split between the brackets.

Comment: I updated my answer to fit these requirements. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it :)). By any chance is there a way to print(item) without having it contained between the [ ]? so that it is only a pure list?

Comment: `print(f"({item[0], item[1], item[2]})")`
should do the trick. It will print: `(element, reason, time)`.Be careful to only use this, when there are 3 elements. Otherwise it will raise and `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses regex to extract all the values between ( ) and `literal_eval` + a custom class to parse the data into objects with the desired attributes:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re


class Fault:

    def __init__(self, stats):
        element, *reason, time = literal_eval(stats)
        self.element = element
        self.reason = reason[0] if reason else ''
        self.time = time

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}("({self.element!r}, {self.reason!r}, {self.time!r})")'



data = "[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]"

matched = re.findall(r"\(.+?\)", data)
print([Fault(m) for m in matched])

f = Fault("('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63')")
print(f.element)
print(f.reason)
print(f.time)
```

Output:

```
[Fault("('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63')"), Fault("('Load 23A_UF', '', '11.37')")...]

G 05
Over-Speed
1.63
```